# Spring Boot, Calling A Method After all the Spring Beans and ApplicationContext have been destroyed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Where can I define a method in a Spring Boot application, which gets called when all the beans in the application has been destroyed and the application is just about to exit.

I want this method to be called after the @PreDestroy method of all the beans has been finished.

Comment: Checkout shutdown hooks https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jvm-shutdown-hook-java/

Comment: Maybe [ContextClosedEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events) will be helpful...

Comment: Tried that, but that gets call before the predestroy method of other beans.

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem. The only solution I could find is to explicitly close the application context "((ConfigurableApplicationContext)ctx).close()" and then calling whatever method I want. But I feel that this is not a very clean solution. Did you find a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

### Since Spring Boot 2.5.1 you can do:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

SpringApplication.getShutdownHandlers().add(Runnable shutdownHandler);
```

According to their [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplicationShutdownHandlers.html):

> Shutdown handlers are guaranteed to be called only after registered
> {@link ApplicationContext} instances have been closed and are no longer active.